# Why does using range work with this function but using the list name doesn't?

Tags: python

Working code:

```
def censor(text, word):
    words_split = text.split()
    for a in range(len(words_split)):
        if words_split[a] == word:
            words_split[a] = "".join("*" * len(word))
    return " ".join(words_split)
```

This one censors the word in a string
Not working code:

```
def censor(text, word):
    words_split = text.split()
    for a in words_split:
        if words_split[a] == word:
            words_split[a] = "".join("*" * len(word))
    return " ".join(words_split)
```

The second one gives me the error:
"list indices must be integers, not str"
How can I get the 2nd code to work similarly to the first one

Comment: a contain list item in the second method whereas a contain item index(integer) in the first method. .

Comment: so just use `if a == word:` in the second one.

Comment: Read the documentation!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Why is there so much hate?

Comment: Because you lack minimal understanding, and should half-read the documentation or follow a few google links before turning to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as explained in [the documentation for `for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), these two loop kinds do different things.

`for a in words_split` will give you the values `a` in `words_split`, so `a` is already a string value and `words_split[a]` doesn't exist.

Iterating using the range gives you the *indices* in `words_split`, so you pass those to `words_split[]` to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

in the first one a is the index of the element, in the second one a is the element itself

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

index:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print i
```

gives:

```
0
1
2
```

element:

```
for element in l:
    print element
```

gives:

```
a
b
c
```